# Spinner setSelection returns null exception in some devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner

The `setSelection(int position)` of my spinner returns null point exception only in some devices. I've found a solution which I have to use `setSelection(int position, boolean animate)` instead. However, that solution implies the `onItemSelected` call, so in my case I cannot use `setSelection(int position, boolean animate)`. Is there any other solution for that problem? And why does that happen only in some devices?

Here is an example of my code:

```
holder.spinnerService.setSelection(_serviceSelected.getAmount() - 1);
```

I debugged the code and the position `_serviceSelected.getAmount() - 1` exists into the `spinner`, so that is not the problem.

Error track:

```
08-07 10:56:46.844    9980-9986/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-07 10:56:47.019    9980-9980/? E/ERROR﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6327)
        at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16581)
        at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:654)
        at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:617)
        at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:433)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1091)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:592)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1054)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:592)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16581)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16581)
        at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1870)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2130)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1626)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1789)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the NPE to figure out what is null.

Comment: Is a `textview` that is returning null. Take a look the track

Comment: Make sure you pass the parent view when you inflate the spinner layout: `inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);`

Comment: Yeah it worked!! Thank you very much! Do you know why that happened only in some devices?

Comment: This line of code has been added to TextView in Android 4.4 and is causing the crash when layout params are null: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L6124

Comment: Humm I got you! Thank you very much for that :)